# Does a text to class diagram generator exist?

Tags: software-recommendation

I would like to generate a [class diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram) as an image. This package should read an input text file and generate the output. I don't want to draw it (so [Dia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dia_%28software%29) is not the solution for my problem). I am searching for an equivalent for class diagrams simmilar to [Graphviz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphviz) with graphs.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I've run across so far is [yuml](http://yuml.me).

It's got it's own particular syntax (and I've hit a few random snags every so often), but overall, it does a pretty good job, and it even provides a couple different styles and formats for output.

If items in your diagrams grow too large vertically, try forcing the diagram to a horizontal (dir:lr) direction.

Just be sure to save your original text, in case you lose the link(s) to your diagram(s).